# OpenGL Tutorial Error

Tags: c++, opengl, driver, ubuntu-12.04

I managed to build the tutorials from [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) but when executing them an error occurs:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
Serial number of failed request:  34
Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

Google told me that this error is related to the graphics driver somehow, so maybe information about my system is useful; I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on a Samsung 700Z7C notebook.

Comment: You should probably post the exact graphic card you're using and what driver.

Comment: it seems like your graphics card / driver doesn't support the main features, do you have a driver installed correctly? try to run glxgears and say if it works

Comment: What's the output of `glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL (renderer|version|shading)"`?

Comment: Yes, glxgears works.  
For the glxinfo I got:  
`OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)  ; 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4  ;
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20`

edit: I'm sorry, I don't know how to put line breaks in here.

Comment: @AndreasT: Sadly you can't put linebreaks in comments.  Just edit it into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

> OpenGL version string: **2.1** Mesa 8.0.4

Third page, ["What You Need"](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/About%20Need.html):

> ...but to execute the code, you must have a programming environment that allows OpenGL. Specifically, **you will need hardware capable of running OpenGL version 3.3**. ...

[Samsung 700Z7C notebook:](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP700Z7C-S01US-specs)

> Graphics: External or Integrated:     External (**Optimus**)

[Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus#Unix_support):

> When no software mechanism exists for switching between graphics adapters, the system cannot use the NVIDIA GPU at all, even if an installed graphics driver would support it.

[Make sure you're routing your GLX requests to the NVidia chip (with the proprietary drivers) and not the Intel one.](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu)

Comment: I did not know that. I thought Optimus was available by default. Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you should check - does your graphics card support OpenGL 3.3 (I believe that's the version used in the arcsynthesis book), are your drivers up to date, and is your code actually ok? We can probably cross 3 out, it would still help if you told us which example you were trying to run though.

Comment: I compiled the first tutorial. Well, according to genpfault's answer, I have to install "Bumblebee" first. I will try that out.