# OpenGL tutorial (Arcsynthesis) failed X request

Tags: c++, opengl, driver, ubuntu-13.10

I am getting an error running the first project of the Arcsynthesis tutorial. It builds just fine.

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  34
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480271/opengl-tutorial-error) seems to have the answer, but I don't understand what's going on enough to apply it to my situation. Another issue could be that my graphics card simply can't run the right version of OpenGL (Arcsynthesis uses OpenGl 3.3, I believe).

My graphics card is an `Intel 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2`, I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. As was requested in the linked question, I ran `glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL (renderer|version|shading)"` and got this (note the OpenGL version):

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 9.2.1
```

Any help?

Comment: GLX OpCode 34 = `glXCreateContextAttribsARB (...)`. Now, if your GL implementation is limited to OpenGL 1.4, chances are very good that your GLX server does not understand this function because it comes from the extension: `GLX_ARB_create_context`. There's not a whole lot you can do about this on a GPU that old. You could always upgrade Mesa, but you should not expect hardware support for anything newer than 1.4 on that GPU. You can probably get Vertex Buffer Objects (1.5), but not much else newer than 1.4.

Comment: Ah... Just in case, how would I upgrade Mesa?

Comment: No idea, I have never used Ubuntu. However, since Ubuntu is derived from Debian, you could try `apt-cache search mesa`. There may be a separate package for Mesa 10.0. Otherwise, you might need to use a newer version of Ubuntu, I really could not say because I always use Debian Unstable/Testing.